# google bigquery php api syntax validity check before actually running the query

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a use case where a sql query [to be run on gcp-bigquery] is generated programmatically based on the params, and I need to notify the user if the query that has been generated is valid or not.

Currently I simply send the query to the bigquery api endpoint, and it returns with either result or error.

The problem is when you just want to check if this query will run or not, and the query actually runs, it can cause problems in billing.

Is there a flag or a parameter [or maybe an API endpoint] that I can use while sending the query to tell the server that run it in emulated mode so that no billing occurs and I can get the 
 simple true / false for whether the query was valid or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use so called dry-run. check respective parameter in API [`configuration.dryRun`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.dryRun)